# Оптимизация SQL запроса при выборе только лучших игроков

Tags: c#, sql

По умолчанию, я выгружаю всю базу данных и сортирую лучших игроков по процентам побед. Но это грубая ошибка, когда в базе будет очень много зарегистрированных пользователей. Возможно ли выбрать 100 лучших игроков, по процентам побед прямо в SQL запросе? Чтобы я выгрузил только их.

**Server version: 8.0.31 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.**

Запрос:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PlayerRankData>> GetRankByWinRate()
{
    try
    {
        return await Db.QueryAsync<PlayerRankData>("select charactername as CharacterName, objid as ObjId, level as Level, " +
            "crank as PlayerRank, nw as NumberWinners, nl as NumberLosses from characters");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        DebugException.Instance.Execute(exception);
        Console.WriteLine($"Method: {nameof(GetRankByWinRate)}. Message: '{exception.Message}'");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Контракт:

```
public sealed class PlayerRankData
{
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }
    public long ObjId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int PlayerRank { get; set; }
    public int NumberWinners { get; set; }
    public int NumberLosses { get; set; }
    public long TimeWinRate { get; set; }
    public long TimeByLevel { get; set; }
    public long TimeNumberFights { get; set; }
}
```

Cортировка:

```
if (_gameClient.PlayerRankDatas == null)
{
    data = await _rankTableRepository.GetRankByWinRate();

    _gameClient.PlayerRankDatas = data.OrderByDescending(
        rate => InternalWinRateCalculate(rate)).Take(_appConfiguration.RankMaxTakePlayers).ToList();
}
else
    _gameClient.PlayerRankDatas = _gameClient.PlayerRankDatas.OrderByDescending(
        rate => InternalWinRateCalculate(rate)).Take(_appConfiguration.RankMaxTakePlayers).ToList();
```

Comment: Бессмысленно. Чтобы дать сотню лучших - надо выбрать всех, отсортировать по проценту, и только потом отделить нужное количество. Очевидно, это дольше. Хотя выиграешь на времени передачи результата. *По умолчанию, я выгружаю всю базу данных и сортирую лучших игроков по процентам побед.* - что-то я сортировки в упор не вижу..

Comment: @Akina потому что ее я тут и не пытался вставить. Вопрос именно в запросе.

Comment: Я бы это делал так: 1) создал бы вычисляемую колонку `NumberWinners / NumberWinners + NumberLosses` 2) Определил бы индекс по этой колонке (при необходимости - добавить доп колонку в индекс на случай, если проценты побед одинаковые)

Comment: Если вопрос в запросе - то зачем тут вообще код на шарпе? ограничьтесь собственно SQL-запросом. Заодно укажите, что Вы разумеете под словами "процент побед" - можно прямо написать соотв. выражение. Ну и вообще см. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3. да, кстати, а какая СУБД? включая точную версию..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    charactername AS CharacterName,
    objid AS ObjId,
    level AS Level,
    crank AS PlayerRank,
    nw AS NumberWinners,
    nl AS NumberLosses
FROM characters
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (nw + nl) > 0 THEN nw / (nw + nl) ELSE 0 END DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: *`ORDER BY (nw + nl) > 0 ? nw / (nw + nl) : 0`* Сервер БД офигеет от такой конструкции..

Comment: @Alexey,
SELECT
    charactername AS CharacterName,
    objid AS ObjId,
    level AS Level,
    crank AS PlayerRank,
    nw AS NumberWinners,
    nl AS NumberLosses
FROM characters
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (nw + nl) > 0 THEN nw / (nw + nl) ELSE 0 END DESC
LIMIT 100;

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: Странно считать какую-то сложную штуку только для `group by`, я бы всё-таки отдал её в виде поля, а в `group by` можно указать номер этого поля.